# Anybody knows why Chainlink's PriceFeed return price value with "int" type while price should always >= 0?

Tags: chainlink

The code for get latest price in PriceFeed is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract PriceConsumerV3 {

    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Aggregator: ETH/USD
     * Address: 0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331
     */
    constructor() public {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the latest price
     */
    function getThePrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return price;
    }
}
```

Note that within function `getThePrice`, the line `int price`, why Chainlink use `int` type on price? Why not just `uint` type? And is it possible to get negative price from Chainlink PriceFeed?

Answer (score 11):

The Chainlink Data Feeds use `int` instead of `uint` because some prices can be negative, like when [oil futures dropped below 0](https://www.ig.com/en/news-and-trade-ideas/what-do-negative-oil-prices-mean--200507).

Comment: Thanks @Patrick, it is straightforward and concise.